# How to change Visual Studio 2013 Solution Explorer font rendering mechanism?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, visual-studio-2013, gdi

I am using VS 2013, and I am also using [MacType](https://code.google.com/p/mactype/) which allows the Windows font rendering to be similar to Mac.

In Visual Studio, I can see the Performance Explorer panel font is rendered as I wished. However the Solution Explorer panel is not.

Is there anyway to make Solution Explorer font rendering to be the same ?

On the sideline, there is an extension named [TextSharp](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7aafa2ea-8c54-4da8-922e-d26bf018514d) which let you choose how Text Editor renders font: Aliased/Grayscale/ClearType. I wonder if we can do the same for Solution Explorer?

[image: Different font rendering results]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you can only open that on a Performance Explorer. On the Other hand, it would still work for what you are trying to do. Only that's invisible in solution explorer

P.S. You posted this question on the wrong site. This is supposed to be on stackoverflow. :)